# React - import multiple images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react to create an app, and want to import images but i can't just write `<img src="path/filename.jpg" />`

I've got an array with every path+filename of images from a repository. The content of the array depends on amount of file in the repo.

I want to create a gallery, with every images from the repository...but as i get path and filenames of images dynamically (when the component is create) i can't just import images in the top of my file like `import img1 from "../images/.../image1.jpg"`
For the moment i've got the array (called gallerie), and I iterate throught it like that, but images arn't loaded :

```
{this.state.gallerie.map((image, i) => {
    return (<img key={i} src={image}/>);
})}
```

How is it possible to display images with their path ? Should I convert them into Base64 ?

Comment: What is `image` inside `.map`? It's a link?

Comment: It's the path of the image (a string) ... something like that : `../images/gallerie/img1.jpg`

Comment: why can't you import all the images in a loop? Like e.g. `const images = this.state.gallerie.map(image => require(image))` or something like that

Comment: How can I do that ?  I already import an image in other component like that `import MaisonInt from '../images/maison.jpg';` but it's only in the top of the fileout of the class...And I want to do it dynamically, with values from the repository

Comment: I do not understand `require();`...I already see this method during my researches, but in my app, when i use it, I've got `Error: Cannot find module './nameImage.jpg'`

Comment: `import a from 'b'` is almost the same as `const a = require('b')`

Comment: I try to import one of the images from the array "manually", with import Img from 'path/filename.jpg', and it work, but with require('path/filename.jpg') there is an error : "Cannot find module 'path/filename.jpg'"

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `path` to change a relative path into absolute, so your app can fetch the image properly.

```
import * as path from 'path';

{this.state.gallerie.map((image, i) => {
    const path = `${path.resolve(__dirname)}${image}`;

    return (<img key={i} src={path}/>);
})}
```

Comment: I try that, I havn't any errors, but in my inspector i see `<img src="../images/gallerie/nameImage.jpg">` (so the good path), but image can't load

Comment: Use right mouse click on the link in inspector and choose "open in a new tab" and paste the whole link here.

Comment: When I open in new tab, it open the app, not the image (single-page app) but here is the link : http://localhost:3000/images/gallerie/quiberon8.jpg

Comment: @siraxtas It won't work locally. You have to deploy your app on a host, so the `path` will reference to your domain. The result will be `yourdomain.com/images/gallerie/someImg.jpg`

Comment: I don't have a host...I have to build the app, and deploy it to the host (ex wamp)?

Comment: @siraxtas You want to publish it, right? So u'll have to build the app and store it somewhere.

Comment: "build the app", ok I use `npm run build`...And then ? I've got a wamp server running on my computer, for tests it should be possible to puts file generated by the build command in the `www` directory in `wamp` ?